# Trying to use SVG/Canvas/Flash in PhoneGap for iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone, ios, html, cordova

I started application in PhoneGap(first for Android and after that I will made iPhone app). I am not sure what is better to use for this problem. I would need to animate drawing diagonally lines between two dots. I am not sure if I can use SVG for that, or maybe Flash, or maybe Canvas. Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Flash for Android and Built-in Core Animation for iOS.